# Visual Studio 17 Build Failure, Invalid Configuration

Tags: visual-studio, build, configuration

I couldn't build my solution, I get this at the Output:

```
Build started ...
Build Failure. Error: Invalid Configuration
Parameter name: configurationName
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

But if I build project one by one (no as all solution) it's ok, Configuration Manager is ok too. It seems to me, that answer is pretty simple, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strangely, but changing my projects path helps. I don't know why and how it works.

Answer (score 5):

**Right click** on the **solution**, **Disbale Lightweight Solution Load** then reload the solution. 
It surely will impact the loading time, but it will fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

After failing to disable Light weight solution load few times, I simply copied the entire solution to a new folder and re-opened it. that fixed the issue for me.